# Monitoring software for watching cms versions (with automatic notifications when there are cms in need of updates)

Tags: content-management-system, monitoring, nagios

I have been googling a lot and it's hard to find the right thing, so I hope this wonderful community can just give me some tips.
At first: I am learning PHP, but still a beginner.

Really short: I am looking for a simple and easy to customize monitoring software.

I want to have an overview of a few cm systems and already found out some "hacks" how to get the version number without login into the backend (even if the cms is hiding the version in the code).
The software should just run a function once a day which determines/gets/reads the version number of 'cms project 1' and then displays the project names + versions in a list. If there are necessary updates the software should send an email to a specific person, saying which project needs an update.
So I even would try to program the function which checks the versions myself, also the sending mail function shouldn't be a big problem but I still could need a good basis.

What I found for example is [Shinken](http://www.shinken-monitoring.org/), which kinda seems to be too powerful for something as simple as what I want.

What looked so far more interesting is [Nagios Core](https://www.nagios.com/products/nagios-core/), which seems to be more simple and easy to handle for me. Is there anybody who can recommend this?

Sorry for this long request, being a simple webdesigner for the past years I feel pretty lost. So thanks in advance for EVERY input. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In general - you want a "do it better" button.

I didn't know this :(

What you should understand:

1. At first you can add each CMS check as service in nagios
2. on every service you can add check command, like `needs_upgrade_%service_name%`.
3. You can check this in a `check_period`, like 86400(1 day)

So, what you need - is just implement check commands `needs_upgrade_%service_name%`

Is that an answer to your question ? If you ask for implementation of check commands for services, i think, you should say - what services you are want to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, that is already quiet interesting. But I have not started yet, first I have to choose the right software. You seem to already have been working with Nagios: can you recommend it for a rookie?

Comment: Nagios is a very good monitoring software. 

Cons is a big community

Pros - it hasn.t built in graphs. But there're many software, that realize them.

I have good experience with nagios, but now i'm using icinga2, which is a nagios fork and uses nagios checks.

My advice is to stay with nagios. Or if you strongly need graphs and low number(less than 10000) of resourses use zabbix.  

You should understand, that any monitoring software have no magic - it's just check what you say to it. With any software you should write your own checks, or pay to some company to their checks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. Should take a deeper look at it. :)